# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in range 0..5, inclusive: 6 : in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am implementing the gallery of the **photo_view** package on flutter, https://pub.dev/packages/photo_view the problem I have is that when I add more than 6 images to the gallery to be able to move it, it only scrolls 6, when I put more than 6 images in: **List  galleryItems** Me The following error appears when executing it:

[image]

My `List <GaleriaItem> galleryItems` is:

```
List<GaleriaItem> galleryItems = <GaleriaItem>[
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag1",resource: "assets/galeria/g1.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag2",resource: "assets/galeria/g2.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag3",resource: "assets/galeria/g3.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag4",resource: "assets/galeria/g4.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag5",resource: "assets/galeria/g5.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag6",resource: "assets/galeria/g6.jpg",),

  GaleriaItem(id: "tag7",resource: "assets/galeria/g7.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag8",resource: "assets/galeria/g8.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag9",resource: "assets/galeria/g9.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag10",resource: "assets/galeria/g10.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag11",resource: "assets/galeria/g11.jpg",),
  GaleriaItem(id: "tag12",resource: "assets/galeria/g12.jpg",),
];
```

In my main class I have:

```
Table(border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.white,width: 2.5,style: BorderStyle.solid),
          children:[ 
            TableRow(children: [
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[0], onTap: () {open(context, 0,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[1], onTap: () {open(context, 1,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[2], onTap: () {open(context, 2,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
            ],),
            TableRow(children: [
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[3], onTap: () {open(context, 3,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[4], onTap: () {open(context, 4,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[5], onTap: () {open(context, 5,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
            ],),

            //When I increase this following TableRow the error I mentioned appears

            TableRow(children: [  
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[6], onTap: () {open(context, 6,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[7], onTap: () {open(context, 7,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
              Container(child:GaleriaItemThumbnail(galeriaItem: galleryItems[8], onTap: () {open(context, 8,galleryItems);},),color: Colors.black,),
            ],),
```

Which may be? I am working with the sample codes that appears in photo_view, the only thing I have changed is the container, which is now a Table and TableRow.

Comment: Can you show the complete code? At least the builder code of the gallery widget (that contains your `Table`)

Comment: I just solved it, it seemed so silly but it was simply to clean my project with: flutter clean and rerun it, apparently I used a lot of reload and it didn't save me the changes, anyway Thank you very much for wanting to collaborate. :)